# GTK# GUI designer for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: forms, visual-studio, user-interface, mono, gtk#

I'm trying to make an application in C# that can download, install and manage various games that I and a few friends'll be making.

I know how I'm gonna do it, but I want users to be able to use this app on both Windows and Linux as most games will run on both. That's not the big issue, I know how I'm gonna get that working. Ohhhh, the power of Mono and GTK#.

The issue is, however, that for GUI-designing I can't figure out how to design GTK windows within Visual Studio just like you can with Windows Forms. I don't know if there's an add-in or whateverthelike, I just need some way of designing my GUIs for Linux.

I am running Visual Studio Express 2015, on Windows 10.

Comment: The GTK# designer is an exclusive feature of MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Same situation here, I'm going to use a ubuntu VM and monodevelop for the GTK part, just copy files over to Windows after and VS should compile it fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a public version of a Visual Studio embedded GTK (+/2/3) Designer, let alone one that supports GTK#.

As far as Mono GTK# goes, it's designer is called 'Stetic' and is embedded into MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio.

Stetic has a GUI based designer but also uses the files produced from that designer to generate the C# code from a xml file (gui.stetic) and combine that with user written code (actions/events/etc...) via C# partial classes.

You can also use the Glade Designer (older versions) and import them into MD/XS and it will convert them to a gui.stetic files and thus create the C# classes for your UI. This is what I used to do when I needed to knock out a complex GUI prototype quickly. Stetic can really try your patience with the ways it works, but in the end, personally I would skip the Stetic and Glade GUI designers and just code the GTK# containers, widgets and actions in straight C#.

- http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/stetic-gui-designer/
- [Stetic GUI Designer Move to Glade for Gtk#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766079/stetic-gui-designer-move-to-glade-for-gtk3)
- [GUI building with GTK#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743512/gui-building-with-gtk?rq=1)
- [MonoDevelop editor GUI designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085476/monodevelop-editor-gui-designer?rq=1)
- https://glade.gnome.org