# Currently tools such as buttons or labels are also not available. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gtk2

In visual studio 2019 for mac, my toolbox is empty when I'm trying to make a GTK# 2.0 form. How can I have toolbox populated with tools such as buttons and labels? As these are not available in my toolbox right now.

I have deleted and re-installed visual studio 2019 for mac. However, the toolbox remains empty.

There is no code required to solve the problem as Im just trying to populate the toolbox on visual studio 2019 for mac.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You might want to take a look into Glade#.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928901/gtk-gui-designer-for-visual-studio-2015

Comment: I too have not seen any integration in Visual Studio for a GTK designer. Qt yes, GTK no.